# RoR getting things to goto the right places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested

I have a few questions maybe if I can just tie them up all into one quick go here this could be a good reference for later.

I would like to render a partial [comments/new] in [posts/show].  Now being on our current page/show of posts#show we would be using the posts_controller.rb our model will be the one[s] we would like to call on at any point. -- I need to render [comments/new] in the [posts/show] with the comments_controller.rb enabled for that piece.

second the rake routes shows you a list of routes that are created for you.

```
           post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
        new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
       edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
            post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

not sure what everything on this list is or how it works need some help on that one.

class and subclasses? can you have sub-sub-classes and how does linking a class and a subclass work inside of a simple app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are not strictly tied to your controller. Rails is automagically set so that in the `new` action of the `comments` controller, it will try to render the `views/comments/new` view as long as there is no view specified.

You want to call an action from another action. You should not do that. You can call controller method that are not action from an action, but never an actual action.

The shortest answer would be, build an empty comment in the post show actioncontroller (as you probably do).

```
def show
 @post = Post.find params[:id]
 @comment= Comment.build
end
```

and in the view do :

```
<%=render "comments/form" %>
```

EDIT: corrected a typo, here it is rendering what we call a partial. A partial file always start with the _ character, but when you call it in the view, you do not put the _ in the path.

But maybe, a more important question is "do you need a new action in comments". Obviously your comments are always used in posts and you never have a use case asking for a comment created ex nihilo. In a case of a basic blog, i would only have a create and update action in my comments controller that would end with a redirect to post_show_path or :back

Nested resource are not really the best answer to your problem, it would be more fitted for something like a photo gallery where you have pages displaying a single photo :

```
galleries/:id_gallery/photo/:id
```

Using nested routes in a post/comment context, that would mean that you want to have a dedicated view to create a comment, and a view for each comment. You do not really need that.

Comment: I am not sure what I need to do I am trying to build these items as individual things and then incorporate them all as small pieces to make up a bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

:url => { :action => "create", :controller => "posts" }

anytime you can specify a :url I can use this format to call a specific controller and action no matter were I am playing in the views. I can render a partial with this :url in the pages#index then rails know hey don't use the pages controller use the posts controller.